# Changes event does not trigger in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing an angular directive. Here is the code:

```
'use strict';
app.directive('mcategory', function (MainCategory, $rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<select data-ng-model="selectedMainCategory" data-ng-options="mainCategory.mainCategoryId as mainCategory.mainCategoryName ' +
        'for mainCategory in mainCategories" data-ng-change="mainCategoryChanged()"></select>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
        var elm = angular.element(element);
        elm.attr('id', attr['id']);
        elm.attr('name', attr['name']);
        elm.attr('class', attr['class']);
        MainCategory.get().then(function (mainCategories) {
            scope.mainCategories = mainCategories;
        });
        scope.selectedMainCategory = false;
        scope.mainCategoryChanged = function () {
            if (!scope.selectedMainCategory) {
                return;
            }                
            $rootScope.$broadcast("mainCategoryChanged", { mainCategory: scope.selectedMainCategory });
        };
    }
};
})
```

`MainCategory` is a service and it works ok.

The problem is that `selectedMainCategory` is always `undefined` and `mainCategoryChanged()` event is not triggered when user selects another category in the select element. I think I have made a silly mistake but it is more than 2 hours that I can't solve the problem. Any help is appreciated in advance.

**UPDATE**
Here is the service:

```
'use strict';
app.factory('MainCategory', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/MainCategory/GetMainCategories').success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject    );            
            return deferred.promise;            
        }
    };
})
```

When I `'/MainCategory/GetMainCategories'` url in the browser I get all the categories in the correct json format.

Comment: Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xj3h4/
I guess you have problem with `MainCategory` service.

Comment: But the service returns the values and the `select` element options are generated.

Comment: With service:
http://plnkr.co/edit/EnoWHFblwLRMEpmDCnuw?p=preview
All is work fine.
can you show view and controller?

Comment: **SOLVED** I was sure that I have made a silly mistake. There was a typing mistake in the model that I was returning. I am using `mainCategoryId` in `data-ng-options` but the model was `mainCetegoryId`. Because it was showing the options I never thought about typing mismatch. Thanks any body.

Comment: $http.get returns a promise already so you can simply your service .get() method to return the result of the $http.get method. This would not change your usage in the directive.